# Collect two linq queries in one query

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I have the following entity framework methods

```
maList = (from p in db.full
                  where (p.mc_object.Contains(str))
                  group p by p.mc_object into g
                  orderby g.Count() descending
                  select new StringIntType
                  {
                      str = g.Key,
                      nbr = g.Count(),
                      par="object"
                  }).ToList();

maList = (from p in db.full
                  where (p.mc_owner.Contains(str))
                  group p by p.mc_owner into g
                  orderby g.Count() descending
                  select new StringIntType
                  {
                      str = g.Key,
                      nbr = g.Count(),
                      par="owner"
                  }).ToList();
```

I would like to make them in one query.

Comment: You could delete one of the queries, then you'll only have one left... job done. Seriously, are we meant to guess how you'd like to combine these queries? What data do you expect at the end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Concat`:

```
var objects = from p in db.full
              where (p.mc_object.Contains(str))
              group p by p.mc_object into g
              orderby g.Count() descending
              select new StringIntType
              {
                  str = g.Key,
                  nbr = g.Count(),
                  par="object"
              };

var owner = from p in db.full
            where (p.mc_owner.Contains(str))
            group p by p.mc_owner into g
            orderby g.Count() descending
            select new StringIntType
            {
                str = g.Key,
                nbr = g.Count(),
                par="owner"
            };

maList = objects.Concat(owner).ToList();
```

This doesn't look like one query but due to LINQ's deferred execution only one query is sent to the database at `ToList()`.

Comment: That worked fine, but how to do  it in case i have 4 queries, will i use .contact(xxxx).concat(yyyy).concat(zzz) ?

Comment: @Redadublex: since that are even different tables, yes. But that seems not to be the best data model. If tables are so similar you should use one table with another column `Type` or so.

Comment: Yes i agree, i'm struggling with another query in sql server may be if i solve it i'l try to convert it to linq

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Union method

```
maList = (from p in db.full
              where (p.mc_object.Contains(str))
              group p by p.mc_object into g
              orderby g.Count() descending
              select new StringIntType
              {
                  str = g.Key,
                  nbr = g.Count(),
                  par="object"
              })
              .Union(from p in db.full
              where (p.mc_owner.Contains(str))
              group p by p.mc_owner into g
              orderby g.Count() descending
              select new StringIntType
              {
                  str = g.Key,
                  nbr = g.Count(),
                  par="owner"
              }).ToList();
```

Comment: `Union` tries to remove duplicates which is unnecessary here. Both are  different because one has `par="object"` and the other `par="owner"`. `Concat` is like `UNION ALL` in sql and actually it gets translated to that.